# Filter for if rows where ID is same but Value column has different value to first occurrence

Tags: r

I am looking for advice on the principle of filtering a dataset in R. I currently have the below code which allows for easy filtering of records where a value in column 'Value' is within the required list that I have created:

```
ValuesNumber <- 
  read.table(textConnection("CustomerID   Value   
1 Ball
1 Cat
2 Ball
2 Ball
3 Dog
4 Ball
4 Blitz"), header=TRUE)

#Filter for required values only

Values_List <- "Ball|Twist|Tester"

ValuesNumberFiltered <- ValuesNumber[grep(Values_List,  ValuesNumber$Value
),]
```

I am looking to amend this so that the below criteria are met:

1. 'CustomerID' appears in the dataset at least twice
2. The entry in 'Value' column for the second entry does not appear within a list of my choosing.

So for example if working with this dataset:

| CustomerID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ball |
| 1 | Cat |
| 2 | Ball |
| 2 | Ball |
| 3 | Dog |
| 4 | Ball |
| 4 | Blitz |

I would then like to create a new column entitled 'Y/N' which has:

'1' if the value in all occurrences after the first occurrence does not match my list or
'0' if it does not.

So the output would look like this:

| CustomerID | Value | Y/N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ball | 0 |
| 1 | Cat | 1 |
| 2 | Ball | 0 |
| 2 | Ball | 0 |
| 3 | Dog | 0 |
| 4 | Ball | 0 |
| 4 | Blitz | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

Values_List <- c("Ball", "Twist", "Tester")
ValuesNumber %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID) %>% 
  mutate(`Y/N` = +(n() >= 2 & !(Value %in% Values_List)))

  CustomerID Value `Y/N`
1          1 Ball      0
2          1 Cat       1
3          2 Ball      0
4          2 Ball      0
5          3 Dog       0
6          4 Ball      0
7          4 Blitz     1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
ValuesNumber %>%
  group_by(CustomerID) %>%
  mutate(`Y/N` = case_when(
    row_number() == 1 ~ 0,
    grepl(Values_List, Value) ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ 1
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#   CustomerID Value `Y/N`
#        <int> <chr> <dbl>
# 1          1 Ball      0
# 2          1 Cat       1
# 3          2 Ball      0
# 4          2 Ball      0
# 5          3 Dog       0
# 6          4 Ball      0
# 7          4 Blitz     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rm(list = ls())

library(tidyverse)

values_number <- read.table(
  textConnection("CustomerID   Value   
1 Ball
1 Cat
2 Ball
2 Ball
3 Dog
4 Ball
4 Blitz"), header = TRUE)

# Filter for required values only
value_list <- c("Ball", "Twist", "Tester")

count_id <- values_number |> 
  group_by(CustomerID) |> 
  summarise(count = length(CustomerID)) |>       # count the occurance of each customer id
  right_join(values_number, by = "CustomerID") |>     # combined to the original data
  mutate("Y/N" = case_when(
    count > 1 & !(Value %in% value_list) ~ 1,    # if the occurance of customer id > 1 and
    TRUE ~ 0)                                    # the entry did not involved in the list
    )                                            # mark as 1, the others mark as 0
```